# Erase an element from vector by address

Tags: c++, pointers

Good evening, I have a vector with some elements and i have the address of one of those elements (C++) . I have to delete the element from that vector with this address.
For example..

```
std::vector<int> numbers(5);
int* to_delete = &numbers[2];
numbers.erase(to_delete); 
// obviously this doesn't work because vector::erase parameter should be an iterator.
```

This problem comes from an application i'm finishing to create.
It's a recipes app and the recipes are contained in a vector.
I added the "search engine" so i have another vector that contains the addresses of those recips with name similar to the one written in the input box.
But if i want to delete one of them, i should delete from the original recipes vector. 
So the problem comes from here.

So how can i do this? Is this possible? Or i should do with another method?

Sorry for bad english but i'm italian

Comment: Keep in mind that the delete action could invalidate the results in your "search result" vector. Maybe use a vector where each entry is a shared_ptr to a recipe?

Comment: so i will erase the element from search result vector too

Comment: Maybe you should consider storing an index to the other vector instead of a pointer to the value.

Comment: Erasing a pointer or index from the recipe vector both don't solve the problem of invalidating all the other results if you delete the first recipe for instance. Then all the pointers or indices suddenly point to their neighbour. Worse yet, if the vector moves it's content to a new place in memory then all the pointers are pointing to the freed memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While

```
int* to_delete = &numbers[2];
numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + (to_delete - &numbers[0]));
```

will work, there are pitfalls. If any new items are added to and/or existing items are removed from `numbers` between the two lines, the code will result in undefined behavior. But then, dereferencing the pointer will also result in undefined behavior under such circumstances.

If possible, store the index in client code, access the element from the `std::vector` when you need a handle to the object using `index`, and delete the element using the index too.

```
std::vector<int> numbers(5);

size_t index = 2;  // Make sure to use index only after this.

// Access the element using index.
// Use numbers[index];

// Delete the element using the index
if ( index < numbers.size() )
{
   numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + index); 
}
else
{
   // Index is no longer valid.
   // Can't erase from the vector.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + (to_delete - &numbers[0]));
```

Comment: Probably doesn't make a difference, but using `numbers.data()` instead of `&numbers[0]` seems like better style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard functions [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to to obtain the iterator that you would like to delete:

```
auto to_delete_iter = std::next(numbers.begin(), std::distance(&numbers.front(), to_delete));
```

You can use `to_delete_iter` to call `erase`:

```
numbers.erase(to_delete_iter);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/JRk6nl)